# How to ask for review with SKStoreReviewController on macOS?

Tags: macos, swiftui, skstorereviewcontroller

I'm trying to figure out how to use the the `SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()`.

How do I get the review dialogue to show up in a macOS SwiftUI app?

When I call `SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()` in debug mode in my app nothing happens even though the documentation says it should show up every time in debug mode. As far as I can see the `SKStoreReviewController.requestReview(in: UIWindowScene)` call is just for iOS and macCatalyst and not for macOS 12.

I've seen the new SwiftUI API but it is only available from macOS 13:

```
@Environment(\.requestReview) private var requestReview

VStack {

}      
.onAppear {
    requestReview()
}
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the error. It's not showing because my app was set to `Sign to Run Locally` and not to `Development`.

[image]

Comment: In my case on macOS in spite of using Development review didn't show up. To test on the mac `Archive` app > `Developer ID` > `Export` and open the app and test it. Archive option should be `Development ID` and not `Development`

Comment: @user1046037 same as you, the review prompt doesn't show up when debugging on macOS, I am using Xcode 14.3.1, macOS 13.6

Comment: Exporting with Custom and selecting Developer ID instead of development solved this for me on MacOS 13 and 14. As per user1046037 comment.